# Quoted shell parameter expansion

Tags: bash

I have a simple Bash function that gives me a random file from a path expression:

```sh
rand() { ls -d "$@" | shuf -n 1; }
```

It let's me write things like `rand *` or `rand ./Documents/*pdf` to return things like `my_file.txt` or `./Documents/my_file.pdf`
The quotes are needed for handling file names with spaces.

Now I'd like to add a [default value to the function](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), e.g. something like `${@-./*}` (to make `rand` do `rand ./*`). How to I do that, so that the user input is still quoted?

This will make the default value work, but fails when there are files or user input with spaces:

```
rand() { ls -d ${@-*} | shuf -n 1; }
```

This will work for user input, but looks for the literal name `"*"` as the default value, not finding anything:

```
rand() { ls -d "${@-*}" | shuf -n 1; }
```

And this is not a valid substitution:

```
rand() { ls -d ${"@"-*} | shuf -n 1; }
```

(I'm on GNU bash, version 5, in case there are syntactical differences between versions)

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Yep, I am aware that parsing ls output is not the correct way of doing _anything_, but for personal use I'm prepared to live with any edge cases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an `if`? If there's no user input, you don't need to keep it quoted, if there's a user input, there's no need for a default.

```sh
rand() {
    if (($#)) ; then
        ls -d "$@"
    else
        ls -d ./*
    fi | shuf -n1
}
```

or even

```sh
rand() {
    if ((! $#)) ; then
        set -- ./*
    fi
    ls -d "$@" | shuf -n1
}
```

Note that it still breaks (as did the original solution without a default) for file names with newlines (but those who create them deserve it!).

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's the way to go! I'm aware of the edge cases with parsing `ls` output like this, but in reality I have bigger problems to care about! :D  (this script is only used on my computer)